# Rules for connecting nouns with の

Tags: grammar, particles

の has many purposes but the one usage I am having difficulty using correctly is connecting nouns.

The reason this is confusing for me is because at my school we have a Japanese club and one of the native speakers corrected me when saying

> 日本語のクラブ

to just

> 日本語クラブ

so my question is why for some nouns do we need to connect with の and others it is not necessary?

Comment: Why would we not say 学校祭?  Try googling it.

Comment: sorry, I understand that it is a word but I meant you would not say がっこうまつり。Sorry, it was a poor example because there exists a word if you remove the の. Can you still understand my confusion regardless?

Comment: @TylerH That's another curious question, including why we say "Solar system" instead of "Sun system".

Comment: Ok thank you, I've removed that part from the original question

Comment: Ah, thank you broccoli. That read made it much more clear. Thank you